# Disabling inline_styles on TinyMCE for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-4

I would like to force TinyMCE for wordpress to stop adding inline CSS for everything I do during edition.

I found [this page](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:inline_styles) that says that I should add this snippet

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        inline_styles : false
});
```

add to where? The page, and by the way, the entire TinyMCE documentation fails to tell where we should add the valuable snippets they mention.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would note that the `inline_styles` configuration option is only valid for TinyMCE 3.x and if you are using any vaguely modern version of WordPress its using TinyMCE 4 and this configuration option will simply be ignored. WordPress 3.9 was the first version to use TinyMCE 4.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure that you can disable the inline-styles via TinyMCE, however the filter used to change default TinyMCE settings is: `tiny_mce_before_init`, so assuming that `inline_styles` is still a valid option that can be overwritten, you could theoretically do it like this.

```
function my_format_TinyMCE( $init ) {
    $init['inline_styles'] = false;
    return $init;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_format_TinyMCE' );
```

There is a note about it in the [source code](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/f617a2d6d932e658449cef1b7864fb77080ecd09/wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php#L694) and a bit of documentation [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE)